# Unable to get url mod_rewrite to work in xampp(windows 8)

Tags: php, apache, php-7

No matter how much I tried to get url rewrite to work, it just keep failing and I have google searched alot and try alot of codes even here on stackoverflow and none of them worked for me and at the end of the day, am forced to ask for help.

I want, like, for example, when a user click on a link, I want the users' to be shown a pretty format of the website URL in the browser in the manner or structure in the manner of that of facebook, stackoverflow, wikipedia etc are doing like when a user visit `localhost:jokes=edit?4`, it formats it to `jokes/edit/4` or something like that.

First thing I did was to setup Virtual host and the virtualhost I setup is this

```
#Directory structure
<Directory C:/alls>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#this is the default address of XAMPP    
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/alls/ijdb/public"
    ServerName ijdb.localhost
    SetEnv NS_ENV variable_value
</VirtualHost>
```

And in the httpd.conf, I turned all

> AllowOverride

to

> all

and in the hosts file add this

```
127.0.0.1   ijdb.localhost
```

Then, create this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Yet, when I click on any other link apart from the home link, it returns object not found. 
My question is how can I solve it?

I use XAMPP3.2.2 which comes by default with apache 2.2.34

From the error log, this is what I saw there. I don't know if it has something to do with it anyway...

```
[Tue Sep 11 02:07:31.554559 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1012:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 11 02:07:32.123856 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 1012:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 11 02:07:32.239860 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1012:tid 376] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Do you get object not found or page not found?

Comment: @unixmiah Object not found

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that rewrite_module is enabled or not. Go to apache bin and load modules list like `cd c:\xampp\apache\bin && apache2.exe -M`

Then modify your virtualhost as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/alls/ijdb/public"
    ServerName ijdb.localhost
    SetEnv NS_ENV variable_value
    <Directory "C:/alls/ijdb/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Check `c:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log` file for more detail.

Comment: I can get to c:\xampp\apache\bin but can't see apache2.exe -M? Or would I type that inside window console?

Comment: You'll find apache2.exe, using the command "apache2.exe -M", you'll get the list of enabled modules.